# How to access Polymer element's selected value

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I know there are quite a few examples out there on accessing variables in the shadow DOM via javascript, however, after trying many combinations, I still can't seem to get the value of the currently selected name in the following example, which is a core menu wrapped in a paper dropdown, wrapped in a paper-menu-button (wrapped in a core-toolbar).

```
<paper-menu-button halign="right">
  <paper-icon-button icon="social:person"></paper-icon-button>
     <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" halign="right">
        <core-menu id="userselection" class="menu" selected="1" selectedItem="{{userName}}">
            <template repeat="{{s in users}}">
                <core-item label="{{s.name}}"></core-item>
            </template>
        </core-menu>
     </paper-dropdown>
</paper-menu-button>
```

So basically, in my javascript I'm trying to grab the currently selected {{s.name}} value.

My javascript file starts with the following:

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');
```

I've tried things like:

```
this.$.userselection.selected.value, and
app.$.userselection.selected.value, and
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#userselection').selected.value, and
app.$.userselection.selected.value; and
app.shadowRoot.querySelector('#userselection').selected.value
```

None of which work.

The fourth one in the list (for example) causes this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userselection' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing html elements lying within shadow dom area outside polymer template is tricky and definitely more restricted than accessing non-shadow dom elements. Furthermore there is no need to to do that because there are techniques to access certain variables/values lying within *template* tag of a polymer definition(shadow dom area) from outside without using dom query methods.

You need several things to accomplish that:

1. a function that is defined within a polymer template and is triggered when a list-item is selected.(for instance core/paper-item)
2. Polymer [*fire*](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/communication.html) method to communicate with outside world like with other polymer templates.
3. and using *addEventListener* to make an element subscribing for certain events that could be dispatched by any polymer templates.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>pastries</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="my-pastries.html">
</head>
<body>
    <my-pastries pastries="[{'name':'Croissant'},{'name':'Donut'},{'name':'Pretzel'}]"></my-pastries>
</body>
<script>
    // in index.html full access is granted when accessing dom elements also defined within index.html so querySelector works here
    var patriesTemplate = document.querySelector('my-pastries');
    // 3. patriesTemplate subscribes for it's own event pastry-selected occurring within it's template definition
    patriesTemplate.addEventListener('pastry-selected', function(e) {
        // e.detail holds the pastry that is passed to fire method
        console.log(e.detail.name);// Donut
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Polymer template(my-pastries.html):

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
<polymer-element name="my-pastries" attributes="pastries">
    <template>
        <paper-menu-button label="Colored">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="colored"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown colored">
          <core-menu class="menu">
            <template repeat="{{pastry in pastries}}">
              <paper-item on-click="{{setSelectedValue}}">{{pastry.name}}</paper-item>
            </template>
          </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
      </paper-menu-button>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        pastries: [],
        // 1. function to trigger fire method
        setSelectedValue : function(e,detail,sender){
          // get templateInstance' context to have access to the model(pastry)
          var pastry = e.target.templateInstance.model.pastry;
          // 2. fire dispatches pastry-selected event that the element patriesTemplate has subscribed for in index.html
          this.fire('pastry-selected',pastry);
        }
      });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I'll have to chew on that for a bit before I fully grasp it :-) but that does help, thanks! Still wondering if I could reach that value directly though. There must be a way...

Comment: you can try but I recommend you not to wast time to access an element that is not considered to be accessed by ordinary query methods, but good look :)